# SqlDataReader Never Returning False

Tags: c#, sql, sqldatareader

I'm using the `SqlDataReader` to write an Excel workbook with several worksheets. Each worksheet has a header, a body and a footer so I'm using a while loop inside a while loop.

The problem is that `reader.Read()` never returns false for me so eof is never set to false. At the end of the file, I get an error when I try to write the header because the reader is empty.

The specific error message is:

> Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

Please look at my code and help if you can.

```
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
bool eof = false;
bool first = true;

while (!eof)
{
    // write a header 
    // set newHeaderCondition from the Reader -- error occurs here
    if (first)
    {
        reader.Read();
        first = false;
    }

    do
    {
        // write row onto spreadsheet
        eof = reader.Read();   ---- THIS IS NEVER FALSE
    } while (!eof && (reader[0] == newHeaderCondition ));

    // write footer that doesn't contain any reader data
    if (!eof )
    {
        // create a new worksheet
    }
}

reader.Close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SqlDataReader.Read`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read(v=vs.110).aspx) advances reader to the next record and returns `true` as long as there are more rows; otherwise `false`.

The problem is on your **loop condition**, it only execute once (even if there are more rows), revise your while condition and modify it.

Comment: Exactly.  What I needed to do was change my while condition to while (eof != false ....)

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understand the behavior you describe, but I suspect you are misinterpreting your observations.

One obvious mistake is that you are assigning the wrong value to `eof`.  You are assigning `true` to `eof` when there is still data, and `false`, when there isn't any.

You probably meant:

```
eof = !reader.Read();
```

Comment: You are right - I got my true and false upside down for the eof value